# pinchToZoom action doesn't work in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Im trying to create a `UICollectionViewCell` which uses the `AVFoundation` Library to zoom in on the screen while the camera is open. The code works fine in a standard `UIViewController` however when I try to run it inside of my `UICollectionViewCell` I get the error

> error: Illegal Configuration: The pinchToZoom: action from the UIPinchGestureRecognizer to the CollectionViewCell is invalid. Actions cannot be targetted at repeating content.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I think you can't zoom the collectionview  cell using pinchToZoom but you can zoom the content inside the cell and if you want to zoom the cell you might have to use some collectionview layout that changes the size of the cell

Comment: @Shezad I have a UIView inside of the cell that I’m trying to zoom in on but the pinch gesture will only let me attach it to the cell